# Rounding function

Tags: php, rounding

I'm trying to round a number to 1 decimal place.

I've written this code to shorten numbers over 1000:

```
$numbers = array($count);
function format_number($number) {
if($number >= 1000) {
   return $number/1000 . "k";
}
}
foreach($numbers as $number) {
echo "Posts: ";
echo format_number($number);
}
```

For example this makes 15900 15.900k. Now I made a rounding part so it only reads as 15.9k:

```
$rounded = round($number, 1); // e.g. 66.7346 becomes 66.7
```

and echoed it:

```
echo "".$rounded."";
```

but nothing shows.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should tell us what language you're using. I'm assuming php

Comment: Did you reinvent `round()` and `number_format()`?

Comment: format_number has no return statement for <1000. Not related to your problem but its a bug.

Comment: [What are you on about? `round()` works fine](http://codepad.org/Jc5ocXFJ)

Comment: also if theres already the "k" in it, I dont think round() will like it.

Comment: @MightyPork It somehow [does](http://codepad.org/xG2SYJiU).

Comment: Using PHP. Not sure what you mean Mike B. Thanks for the bug report MP, I need to write the 0-999 part yet.
h2ooooooo do you have the above code working? Could you show it to me in pastebin? Because I'm using the same code and getting nothing.

Comment: http://php.net/round http://php.net/number_format

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning anything if the number is less than 1000.

```
function format_number($number) {
    if($number >= 1000) {
        return $number/1000 . "k";
    }
    //What happens here if the number is not 1000?
}
```

I'd rewrite it as this:

```
function format_number($number) {
    $append = '';
    if($number >= 1000) {
        $number /= 1000;
        $append = 'k';
    }
    return round($number, 1) . $append;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd just figured out how to do it by editing the `
        return $number/1000 . "k";` line to `
    return round(($number/1000),1) . "k";` but you're version is a lot cleaner.